# XCode8: UIStoryboard update to latest layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

I need to migrate an old project to latest ios sdk. I'm facing an issue regarding storyboard. The project was last modified in iOS6 era. When I open its `Storyboard` with `xCode8` it still renders in `iOS6` design. Also it was build using **Spring and Struts**. You can see this in following picture.

[image]

The `coordinate system` also malfunctioning as selection shows `y-axis` shifted by 20 or 64 downwards(Based on visibility of `statusbar` and `navigationbar`). You can see it following.

[image]

I've tried turning on/off autolayout and trait collection but nothing worked. Can anyone give me an idea on what needs to be done here. It's a large storyboard and at this point it's not possible to build it from scratch.

PS: If I make a new `Storyboard` in the same project then it renders perfectly and no such issue arises.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what caused this issue but I finally fixed it by comparing existing storyboard with a new one. In source code of existing UIStoryboard there was a field variant(variant="6xAndEarlier") which was causing this issue. I removed it and now It works fine.